# CVS Sticky Tag for one instance of my IDE but no another

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I came in today and saw a bunch of sources listed as

`filename.pl 1.1 1.1`

instead of

`filename.pl 1.1`

in my Eclipse project Navigator. 
Trying to commit it gives me, for example:

`cvs commit: sticky tag '1.1' for file 'filename.pl' is not a branch`

Without resorting to swearing and smashing my work desk, how can I get rid of the sticky tags, I dont think I want to branch every bloody source file when I have to do commits, we're not using version control for any real project management, just to sync between devs, and certainly dont have time to do CVS/SVN/what-have-you maintenance every bleeding month.

Was CVS configured to resort to this ball ache by default? Can it be reverted? 
I don't care if it has to be wiped and redone it's a recent deployment anyway, **any and all suggestions** much welcome!

**EDIT** I have now noticed that on another machine configured with my CVS username it is proper and I see only untagged sources, how can I do this for my Eclipse, described above? I will also check whether I have those files listed as binary or ascii on both machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Eclipse Preferences > Team > File Contents` on the machine in question I had `.cgi` set as binary and on my home setup the default, ASCII, for `.cgi` files, as soon as I checked some sources from my home setup the machine in question recognised next time I tried to update that the files are completely different now and were locked with that sticky label.

To restore it I had to remove the whole project, disconnect, delete CVS metadata, change my settings to ASCII for `.cgi` and checkout again from the repo, solid as a rock since.

Answer (score 3):

Find all files with the name "Entries". Find in files the text "//T". It will be files with "stycky revision"

example

```
/ NodeFinder.java/1.6/Tue Nov 12 05:23:32 2013//
/ OrHtmlGenerator.java/1.103/Wed Dec 4 09:22:02 2013//T1.103
/ PopupTextSearchWindow.java/1.3/Mon Oct 15 11:07:27 2012//
/ PropertyListener.java/1.1/Tue Sep 29 12:57:38 2009//
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  Just want to add that the Entries file is in the CVS directory, usually in the same location as the file in question.  After removing everything after // for my file, I was able to commit to CVS again, phew

Answer (score 2):

Believe I had the same problem. It drove me crazy as I couldn't see what caused it or why it started.

In eclipse open Preferences... and then select:

Team > CVS > Ext Connection Method

Change from "Use an external program to connect" to "Use another connection method to connect".

I have a (bad) habit of sometimes clicking the Restore Defaults button or random preferences sections. I probably did that, forgot about it and had that annoying problem for weeks.

I'm a Mac user. That may be part of the problem. Don't know if the external program is configured the same on all platforms (or even exists).

Comment: Defo noting this, i was also on a mac but i'll answer now as i've fixed it and it was something else.

Comment: ASCII/Binary mismatch on 2 different machines, I suppose our posts crossed paths.