# SQL scripts losing branch reference (CVS) on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs

In the project I'm working on, we have a lot of scripts for create tables, insert some initial data and etc. Each module has its own scripts.

We use **CVS** as our SCM and everything was going fine but I'm facing some problems lately:

When I synchronize the whole workspace, it shows me that some scripts were deleted so I bring these changes to my workspace. What is odd is that when I synchronize again, it shows me that someone added these same scripts.

Looks like Eclipse is losing the branch reference for some files and it only occurs for SQL scripts (at least as far as I noticed).

Example:

[image: Scripts on my workspace.]

These are the scripts on my workspace. I've just checked it out from CVS. Note that the `*create_data_security.sql` is not referencing any branch but the other ones yes (b2012_8_P6). When I synchronize I got this:

[image]

I bring the exclusion to my workspace. But when I synchronize again, I got the addition of the same file again.

[image]

It keeps happening over and over again. Often by we have to switch branch before commiting a change in a script because it suddenly lost its branch reference.

Has anyone gone through some problem like this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941347/cvs-sticky-tag-for-one-instance-of-my-ide-but-no-another sounds similar. Could you give us the output of `cvs status` on one of these files?

Comment: @wds http://tny.cz/f47b47c8